# starting android application

Tags: android

I want my application to be started whenever the phone is turned on or restarted. can anyone give me some suggestions regarding this please.

thanks
kaisar

Answer (score 4):

You can set a broadcast receiver which can notify that the device boot is complete

```
android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"
```

Check this link out

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/